# Issues looping through Azure Storage Accounts with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I have following script that loops trough Azure Storage Account and get few properties out from them.

```
# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Get all Azure subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
# Variables to store access levels and errors
$publicAccessOn = @()
$errorsaccessing = @()

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Output "Subscription: $($subscription.Name)"

    # Select the current subscription
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

  
# Get a list of storage accounts 
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount


# Loop through each storage account
foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
    $storageAccountName = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
    $storageAccountRG = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName

    try {
        # Get a list of containers in the storage account
        $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context -ServerTimeoutPerRequest 30 | Select Name, PublicAccess

        # Check if there are containers in the storage account
        if ($containers -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "No containers found in storage account $storageAccountName. Skipping."  -ForegroundColor Cyan
            continue
        }

            # Display the public access setting
            if ($containers.PublicAccess -eq "Off") {
                Write-Host "Container count is: $($containers.Count) in $storageAccountName"
                Write-Host "PublicAccess Settings is Off in all container in storage account: $storageAccountName" -ForegroundColor Green
                
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Container count is: $($containers.Count) in $storageAccountName"
                Write-Host "PublicAccess Settings is ON in one or more container in storage account: $storageAccountName" -ForegroundColor Red
                $publicAccessOn += $storageAccountName
                
            }
    }
    catch {
        # Handle any errors and log them
        $errorsaccessing += $storageAccountName
    }
}

# Output access levels
#$publicAccessOn

# Output errors
#$errors
}
```

Sometimes checking storage account is it's containers fails and I have created `Try` loop. Currently if I have not access to storage account or the check timeouts it still moves foward in the loop even though I would not want it to. Any clue what to change or add because I'm a bit stuck currently.

Here are two errors messages that can occur during scans.
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I got the same error in my environment.

**Error:**
[image]

The above error  "Key-based authentication is not permitted on this storage account" indicates you don't have access to key authentication in your environment.

To resolve this you can follow these steps:

***Go to portal -> storage accounts->configuration->Allow storage account key access ->check if it is enabled or disabled.***

If it is disabled change to an enabled state like the below:

**Portal:**
[image]

Now I run the same script in my environment and got the container count with public access type.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[I'm getting Error Message: Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401852/im-getting-error-message-key-based-authentication?orderBy=Helpful) by Sumarigo-MSFT.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi, I know that the error is from that settings and I can't change it for some storage accout and thus if the setting is like that I get the error (same as you) and it that case I would want to save that storage account to $errorsaccessing and skip checkking